# subprocess.check_output gives windows error

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I was trying to run this file named `develop.py` written in python. But it gives error. Here is my code:

```
import base64
import getpass
import os
import subprocess
import sys

credentials = subprocess.check_output([
    'openssl',
    'aes-256-cbc',
    '-d',
    '-in',
    'credentials.development'
    ], shell=True)

env = os.environ.copy()
env['CREDENTIALS'] = credentials
env['CONFIG'] = 'config.yaml.development'
env['ENVIRONMENT'] = 'development'

subprocess.check_call(['grunt', 'web:develop'], env=env)
```

Here is the result when I run the file:

```
 E:\QA\QA>python develop.py
    'openssl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "develop.py", line 13, in <module>
           ], shell=True)
        File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 219, in check_output
            raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
        subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['openssl', 'aes-256-cbc', 
 '-d', '-in', 'credentials.development']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Environment:
Windows 10 (64 bit)
Python 2.7

How to fix this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a path problem rather than a Python problem.  The error mentioned is found when Windows cannot find the command you are after.

In this case the command `openssl`.

If `openssl` is not added to `path` or a file path to it is not specified then it would produce this error.

You should therefore check that the path has been added to `path` environment variable, then add it if it has not.

Comment: Got this error now:
``Traceback (most recent call last):
File "develop.py", line 20, in <module>
subprocess.check_call(['grunt', 'web:develop'], env=env)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 181, in check_call
retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 168, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified``

Comment: @M.Morshed  Once again it's a finding the file problem.  Try checking the file path.

Answer (score 1):

that mean
One of this Commandes :

```
'openssl',
'aes-256-cbc',
'-d',
'-in',
'credentials.development'
```

dont Exist in openssl

But if you try this:

```
import base64
import getpass
import os
import subprocess
import sys


credentials = subprocess.check_output(['dir'], shell=True)
env = os.environ.copy()
env['CREDENTIALS'] = credentials
env['CONFIG'] = 'config.yaml.development'
env['ENVIRONMENT'] = 'development'
subprocess.check_call(['grunt', 'web:develop'], env=env)
```

with dir , it will work perfectly bcz the Command exist